# Auto-fit columns in grid display, with maximum columns count

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Can a `display: grid` layout be defined so that a column would take up as much space as it can (ala: `auto-fit`) *but* wrap the row when a maximum number of columns is reached, while not styling the columns individually?

Conceptually, I look at it this way:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(minmax(auto-fit, 12), minmax(0, 1fr));
```

However, in all my efforts it seems that I get *either* `auto-fit` *or* a number of columns. I can't combine the two.

In **flex** it could be achieved in the following way, with a maximum number or 4 columns per row:

```css
.row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -12px;
 }
 
 .row > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  min-width: calc(100%/4);
  padding: 0 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.row p {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(147, 128, 108, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div><p>1 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>2 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>3 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>4 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>5 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>6 of 7</p></div>
  <div><p>7 of 7</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure it can be done or it won't be a grid in this case .. so I guess it's impossible